# Php Folder making with ftp

Tags: php, linux, ftp, webserver, vsftpd

I have a webserver and if I make a folder on that webserver with php the webserver will make the folder. But if I want to create a folder inside the folder I just created, it spits out an error.

> "Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Directory send OK. in C:......."

It probably has to do with the permissions from that folder but I don't know for sure.

Does anyone have an idea?

at server end I tried

```
sudo chown *user* /var/www/
```

but that didn't work.

Code:

```
// config ftp 
include '../config/ftpservers/Ftpserver.php';

// foldername 
$foldername = 'Project-'.$randomtoken.'-'.$projectname;
$dir = "/html/upload/projects/".$foldername;

if(ftp_mkdir($ftpConn, $dir))
{
    $dir2 = "/html/upload/projects/".$foldername.'/mainfiles';

    if(ftp_mkdir($ftpConn, $dir2))
    {
        $dir3 = "/html/upload/projects/".$foldername.'/copys';

        if(ftp_mkdir($ftpConn, $dir3))
        {
            $dir4 = "/html/upload/projects/".$foldername.'/pictures';

            if(ftp_mkdir($ftpConn, $dir4))
            {
                'INSTERT TO DATABASE'
            }else{
                echo "Problem with making directory $dir4";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Problem with making directory $dir3";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Problem with making directory $dir2";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Problem with making directory $dir";
}
```

**EDIT**

I have found the problem it was in the ownership off the created directory.
if the first directory was made it has no owner so i can not make a directory inside off it.

Tried multiple things

I Tried to set **local_unmask** to **022** but that didn't work.
I also tried to **set file_open_mode** to **0777** but that didn't work either. closer by the problem but still coudn't find a way to fix it

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're using please

Comment: I have put my code in

Comment: Thanks. For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Did you check if the folder was created (despite the warning)? + Create the directory using a command-line `ftp` client and post its verbose debug output.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes the folder is created only the folders inside the first folder are not created

Comment: have you tried working in passive mode? FTP servers can be fiddly

Comment: how do you mean passive mode?

Comment: @Sleepwalker The active/passive *transfer* mode has effect on *transfers* only. Not when creating folders. + Unless OP provides us more information (like the logs I have proposed above) or [mcve], we can hardly help.

Comment: I should look into it

Comment: So again, can you create the nested folder using any GUI/commandline FTP client?

Comment: Yes the first directory is made but without an owner

Comment: I'm asking about the *nested* one, not the *first* one!

Comment: Yes i can do that